# Multiplying two bytes

Tags: java, byte

Can somebody explain me why I can't to multiply two bytes in this way?

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 1;
byte c = a*b;
```

or

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 1;
short c = a*b;
```

Why I have to do that in this way?

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 1;
byte c = (byte)(a*b);
```

or

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 1;
int/double/float/long c = a*b;
```

Comment: consider that `255 * 255 = 65535`, which is too large to fit within a byte...

Comment: @MarcB `255` is too large to fit in a `byte` (it's signed in Java), and `255 * 255` is `65025`.

Comment: It is an inconsistency of the language. The product of two `int` can't be guaranteed to fit into an `int`, but `int=int*int` is allowed without casting.

Answer (score 12):

When performing math with `byte`s, *binary numeric promotion* takes place, as specified by the [JLS, Section 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - Otherwise, **both operands are converted to type int**.

(emphasis mine)

That forces you to assign to a type that is at least as wide as `int` or to cast back to `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

Product of two bytes will not necessarily fit into a byte. So Java needs you to tell it that you know what you are doing and confirm that in case of overflow you will get the low-order bits.

Comment: This is not the reason.  By this reasoning, multiplying 2 `int`s would force you to assign to a `long` or cast to an `int`.